# Extending a volume on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I am having some issues extending a newly created partition.

[image]

The idea is that I want the 37.96 GB of Free Space to be added to my DATA (D:) partition, and install Ubuntu on the 25.00 GB unallocated space. I had just installed Ubuntu on my D drive accidentally, so it added an additional 6.xx GB of Linux partition on my D-drive, so the free space *should* be behind the current data on the D drive (even though it seems like it isn't).

Anyhow, the "Extend Volume" option for my `D:` isn't available. How do I clean this up?

Comment: @techie007: Using that third party app allowed me to move up the DATA drive and extend it. Ran into some issues that I couldn't give the drive a letter, but after a reboot and fixing the mbr (due to uninstalling Ubuntu) I could rename it and all data is intact, hurray!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into this exact same issue when partitioning my drive for dual boot XP/7 long ago.  You can use a 3rd party tool like GParted to move and extend the partition.

I wouldn't expect much issue with that since it's a data drive, however an OS drive might require you to run a repair.